# Strange behavior with pam_mount

Tags: mount, cifs, pam, sssd

i have a strange behavior with pam_mount on an Ubuntu 20.04 (firsch installed). The client authenticates to an ADS (UCS server 4.4) with Kerberos. The client has joined the domain and I can login with the domain users.

So far so good.

Now I want to mount the samba shares using pam_mount.

The file [/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pam_mount>
<debug enable="1" />
                <volume 
                        fstype="cifs" 
                        user="*" 
                        path="//srv01.gehr.local/Test" 
                        mountpoint="/data01/Test" 
                        options="sec=krb5i,vers=3.0,cruid=%(USERUID)"
                />
<mntoptions allow="nosuid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other" />
<mntoptions deny="suid,dev" />
<mntoptions allow="*" />
<mntoptions deny="*" />
<mntoptions require="nosuid,nodev" />
<logout wait="0" hup="no" term="no" kill="no" />
<mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />
</pam_mount>
```

If I now log in to the Gnome desktop, the share is not mounted. However, when I log on to the client via SSH, the share is correctly mounted to /data01/Test.

If I create a directory "Test" in my Home and change the line:

```
mountpoint="~/Test"
```

it also works in Gnome (Nautilus).

What am I doing wrong?

with best
pixel

Comment: have you managed to solve the problem in the meantime? I'm interested in the solution too. Thanks